# How to override right click contextmenu on openlayers map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, openlayers

I am a beginner of OpenLayers. I am trying to override right click context menu on the map. Is it possible and how? If anyone have a sample or examples please let me know.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to look at this page:  [Spatial Notes: Capturing right-click events in OpenLayers](http://spatialnotes.blogspot.com/2010/11/capturing-right-click-events-in.html) (not my blog).
I just tested the provided code and it seems to work. Try to copy and paste the code in the initialize function of your page;

```
function initialize() {
   copy the code here
}

<body onload="initialize()">
etc...
```

Then to get the coords from the point location you can look at: [How to display mouse position as tooltip in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15540/how-to-display-mouse-position-as-tooltip-in-openlayers) and use the [getLonLatFromPixel](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLonLatFromPixel) function.

```
var position = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but has nothing to do with OpenLayers.

```
window.oncontextmenu = function( event ){
  alert('you clicked');  
};
```